# How to update link to documents in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Recently, we updated the URL for our Sharepoint site. I have added AAMs to direct any users trying to access the site through the old URL to the new URL. So far, everything has been working fine. Recently, while browsing through a document library, I noticed when I clicked on the ellipses on the name of a document so I could copy the link associated to the document, the URL appears as http://NewSiteURl/http://OldSiteURL/...

I notice it is not every single document in my library that presents links like this, but I do notice it in random documents throughout the library. How can I fix this issue so all links to documents within the library so it doesn't contain the old site url?

Comment: This may help point you in the right direction: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/239883/remove-old-alternate-access-mapping-url

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try on my test environment! Although I would like to avoid editing IIS on the Sharepoint server. Considering the issue is associated to my document library, do you think I should do a reindexing or a crawl after making the changes from the question you linked?

Comment: Hi, I just tried the following: 1) Added a AAM for the old site URL 2) Added an IIS Binding for the old URL 3) IISreset 4) Re-indexed the affected document library and ran an incremental crawl, but I'm still experiencing the incorrect document link formatting.